# Почему первый блок прижимается к левому краю?

Tags: html, css

Не могу понять, в чем может быть проблема.

[Код](https://codepen.io/nomelnomel/pen/pxoYzX):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 670px){
    .sejourline {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    }
}
```

При уменьшении экрана до `670px`, по центру смещается только второй блок, первый остается прижат к левому краю.
 Помогает сдвинуть только `margin-left`, но хотелось бы, чтобы процесс проходил автоматически.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите 100% ширину у `.lineelem`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 670px){
    .sejourline {
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .lineelem {
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

А если уж быть более точным, то у вас немного неверный подход был:

```
.sejourline {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between; /* Эта штука разнесет оба блока  */
}
.lineelem{
    width:100%; /* Это лишнее  */
}
@media screen and (max-width: 670px){
    .sejourline {
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items:center;
    }
}
```